# Help with source of farewell sermon

Tags: hadith, source-identification

AOA
The hadith of "an arab has no superiority..." is not found in any of the sahi sitta. It is supposedly found in musnad ahmed 22978, however that is a completely different hadith when I downloaded an archive. Can anyone give me proof of its origin?

Comment: Linked: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38040/ Note that hadith numbers vary from publisher to publisher. The Arabic text is given so that you can search for it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the hadith in the Musnad:

> حَدَّثَنَا إِسْمَاعِيلُ، حَدَّثَنَا سَعِيدٌ الْجُرَيْرِيُّ، عَنْ أَبِي نَضْرَةَ، حَدَّثَنِي مَنْ سَمِعَ خُطْبَةَ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ فِي وَسَطِ أَيَّامِ التَّشْرِيقِ فَقَالَ: «يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ، أَلَا §إِنَّ رَبَّكُمْ وَاحِدٌ، وَإِنَّ أَبَاكُمْ وَاحِدٌ، أَلَا لَا فَضْلَ لِعَرَبِيٍّ عَلَى عَجَمِيٍّ، وَلَا لِعَجَمِيٍّ عَلَى عَرَبِيٍّ، وَلَا أَحْمَرَ عَلَى أَسْوَدَ، وَلَا أَسْوَدَ عَلَى أَحْمَرَ، إِلَّا بِالتَّقْوَى أَبَلَّغْتُ» ، قَالُوا: بَلَّغَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ، ثُمَّ قَالَ: «أَيُّ يَوْمٍ هَذَا؟» ، قَالُوا: يَوْمٌ حَرَامٌ، ثُمَّ قَالَ: «أَيُّ شَهْرٍ هَذَا؟» ، قَالُوا: شَهْرٌ حَرَامٌ، قَالَ: ثُمَّ قَالَ: «أَيُّ بَلَدٍ هَذَا؟» ، قَالُوا بَلَدٌ حَرَامٌ، قَالَ: «فَإِنَّ اللَّهَ قَدْ حَرَّمَ بَيْنَكُمْ دِمَاءَكُمْ وَأَمْوَالَكُمْ» ـ قَالَ: وَلَا أَدْرِي قَالَ: أَوْ أَعْرَاضَكُمْ، أَمْ لَا ـ كَحُرْمَةِ يَوْمِكُمْ هَذَا، فِي شَهْرِكُمْ هَذَا، فِي بَلَدِكُمْ هَذَا أَبَلَّغْتُ "، قَالُوا: بَلَّغَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ، قَالَ: «لِيُبَلِّغِ الشَّاهِدُ الْغَائِبَ»

[Link](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13157/23977). The number is 23489.